# How to position an svg to vertically fill a variable height div?

Tags: svg

I've created some svg graphics that I would like to set as backgrounds in some variable height divs. I'm trying to use them as a sprite, so one svg file has a few groups, each with its own id, and I'm using those ids to specify which background is rendered in each div.

Here's a link to a (non-working) [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/svag2/).

```
HTML:
<svg width="0" height="0">
  <defs>
    <!-- BLUE GRAPHIC -->
    <g id="blue_background">
      <polygon fill="#C8D9E5" points="[...in the fiddle...]"/>
    </g>

    <!-- GREEN GRAPHIC -->
    <g id="green_background">
      <path fill="#49B974" d="[...in the fiddle...]"/>
    </g>
  </defs>
</svg>


<div class="box">
    <h1>asdasdasd</h1>
    <h1>asdasdasd</h1>
    <h1>asdasdasd</h1>
    <svg class="svg1" viewBox="0 0 600 200" >
        <use xlink:href="#blue_background" width="100%" height="100%"></use>
    </svg>
</div>

<div class="box">
    <h1>asdasdasd</h1>
    <h1>asdasdasd</h1>
    <h1>asdasdasd</h1>
    <svg class="svg2" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
        <use xlink:href="#green_background" width="100%" height="100%"></use>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Ideally the graphic would be aligned with the right side, and stretch to fill the div's height.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're describing your SVGs as "backgrounds", I assume you don't need them to push text out of the way.

In that case, I would recommend using absolute positioning for the SVGs (relative to the "box" containers).  With absolute positioning, a height of 100% is valid even if the parent element doesn't have fixed height.

```
.box {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
svg {
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    top:0; right:0;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/svag2/1/

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly. I also ended up setting the width and height of the viewBox attribute to the width and height of the original SVG, and setting the preserveAspectRatio attribute to "none" so that the background image would stretch to fill the height completely.

http://jsfiddle.net/svag2/4/